# QuickFIX/J: Experiencing period disconnects at midnight

Tags: quickfixj

When running our Initiator app through the night, the session gets disconnected for a brief period of time at midnight.

```
INFO: MINA session created for FIX.4.4:initiator->acceptor: local=/10.50.100.130:13565, class org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketSessionImpl, remote=remoteaddr
Mar 17, 2016 01:00:00 AM quickfix.mina.initiator.InitiatorIoHandler sessionCreated
INFO: MINA session created for FIX.4.4:initiator->acceptor: local=/10.50.100.130:13570, class org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketSessionImpl, remote=remoteaddr
```

Our counterparty indicated to not perform any daily disconnects, just weekly ones when the entire market closes.
This is our Quickfix/J config:

```
# default settings for sessions
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
SenderCompID=senderCompID

###########################################################################
# market data connection
###########################################################################

[SESSION]
# inherit ConnectionType, ReconnectInterval and SenderCompID from default
BeginString=FIX.4.4
TargetCompID=acceptor
HeartBtInt=20
SocketConnectPort=443
SocketConnectHost=host
DataDictionary=QuickFix-DataDictionary.xml
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
FileLogPath=log
FileStorePath=filestore
SocketUseSSL=Y
SSLProtocols=TLS
ResetOnLogon=Y
StartDay=Monday
EndDay=Friday

###########################################################################
# trading connection
###########################################################################

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
TargetCompID=acceptor
HeartBtInt=20
SocketConnectPort=443
SocketConnectHost=host
DataDictionary=QuickFix-DataDictionary.xml
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
FileLogPath=log
FileStorePath=filestore
SocketUseSSL=Y
SSLProtocols=TLS
ResetOnLogon=Y
StartDay=Monday
EndDay=Friday
```

Comment: What locale do you have set? The StartDay and EndDay days use the default Locale. Any chance it's not in English?

Comment: > System.out.println(Locale.getDefault())
> 
en_US

Answer (score 1):

Answer: we updated the FIX config on the development machine, but forgot to update it on the machine that runs it.

```
 schedule is daily, 00:00:00-UTC - 00:00:00-UTC
```

Comment: is setting the startTime and endTime makes it so that it never logs out and session isn't interrupted? Because this is what I'm trying to do. if not do you know any way to make it with no interruption?